# easter problem - egg shapes

Tags: recreational-mathematics, ag.algebraic-geometry

Inspired by an exceptionally silly article in today's newspaper I pose the following "egg parametrization problem".

> Give an explicit function $ f(x,y,t) : \mathbb{R}^2\times I \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for each $t$ from interval $I$ the solution set of equation $f(x,y,t) = 0$ looks like an egg.

I'm looking for function that provides most of the various egg shapes found in nature.

Comment: A swallow's egg? and if so, African or European? I see no reason why ths question belongs here instead of, say, http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: They had a hard time creating a model for the Vegreville egg.  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegreville_egg) *Though the surface area of an egg can be difficult to solve mathematically, the enigma of how to assemble two-dimensional tiles onto a three-dimensional egg was eventually solved by Ronald Resch, a computer science professor from the University of Utah, with the assistance of computer-aided design. Resch tiled the egg uses at total of 1108 congruent equilateral triangles,  524 concave hexagons (3-pointed stars), 3,512 visible facets, 6,978 nuts and bolts and 177 internal struts.*

Comment: I made some effort ~two Easters ago to make the image in this question look like an Easter egg: "Which convex bodies roll along closed geodesics?" http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61386/. Even though it was only an ellipsoid, I was inspired by Easter-egg rolling contests.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a nice [Mathematica Demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EggColoredUsingTheRiemannZetaFunction/) (incidentally colored according to the Riemann zeta function), with the shape based on the mathematics of egg shapes described at an *egg curves* website [www.mathematische-basteleien.de](http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/eggcurves.htm):

           [image: Riemannian Egg]
One of the neat constructions explained there is the *Gardener's Egg*:

---

[image: Construction]

---

Answer (score 1):

You might e.g. look at [Cartesian ovals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_oval)